# Convert a big table of value into string

Tags: python

I have a table of value that i want to insert in my python code as a string :

I tried this but not working :

```
        str(3.354219E-03 3.584506E-03 3.830603E-03 4.093597E-03 4.374646E-03
        4.674992E-03 4.995957E-03 5.338959E-03 5.705510E-03 6.097227E-03 
        6.515837E-03 6.963188E-03 7.441252E-03 7.952137E-03 8.498098E-03 
        9.081543E-03 9.705044E-03 1.037135E-02 1.108341E-02 1.184435E-02 
        1.265753E-02 1.352655E-02 1.445522E-02 1.544766E-02 1.650823E-02 
        1.764162E-02 1.885282E-02 2.014718E-02 2.153040E-02 2.300859E-02 
        2.458826E-02 2.627639E-02 2.808042E-02 3.000831E-02 3.206855E-02 
        3.427025E-02 3.662310E-02 3.913749E-02 4.182451E-02 4.469601E-02 
        4.776465E-02 5.104398E-02 5.454845E-02 5.829352E-02 6.229571E-02 
        6.657268E-02 7.114329E-02 7.602769E-02 8.124744E-02 8.682555E-02)
```

Or another way would be to put quotation marks at the beggining and end of line but it's take too much time. If there are some options in Vim or Notepad i would be glad to here about it.

Comment: Putting two quotation marks takes too much time? Are they in a file, can't you read it from a file?

Comment: Not sure what the problem is here. I copied and pasted your data into my IDE, put a couple of quotes around it and voilà - I had a string. I didn't time it accurately but I'd estimate ~5 seconds

Comment: 5 sec how ? the table is in fact longer than that i didn't want to post the full table unfortunately it's not my value so i don't have access to a file which i can work from i'm forced to c/c

Comment: @haswellrefresh I can type very quickly

Comment: yea but image i have 200 lines you won't type 400 quotes marks manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would of course to do it programmatically and immediately split your string so that you retrieve the desired table. If you read a multi-line string, you should use three quotation marks `"""`.

If you are looking for a way to do it in a text editor, here are two solutions that work in VS Code (and many more editors)

1. Column-selection mode. Decently fast, because your inputs are all the same length. You can highlight all rows and then just add quotes accordingly.
2. Reg-ex replacement. You can use the following regex, see explanations [here](https://regex101.com/r/MvHUHe/2). Note that I highlighted the reg-ex mode (next to "1 of 200").

Regardless of the method, by using three quotation marks here as well, Python should be able to read your string including the "inner" quotation marks.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: ok thanks i found, i could do it with notepad also :

Press alt + shilft and voila